# How to simulate HTML5 Drag and Drop in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I am using Python 2.7 and Selenium 2.44.

I want to *automate drag and drop* action in Selenium WD but according to other related posts **Actions in HTML5 are not supported by Selenium** yet. Is there any way to simulate drag and drop in Python?

Here is the code I tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://html5demos.com/drag")
target = driver.find_element_by_id("one")
source = driver.find_element_by_id("bin")
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.drag_and_drop(target, source).perform()
```

and it did not work.

Comment: working solution with Java, please check

https://github.com/vikramvi/Selenium-Java/commit/a1354ca5854315fded8fc80ba24a4717927d08c7

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, HTML5 "drag&drop" **is not currently supported** by Selenium:

- [Issue 3604: HTML5 Drag and Drop with Selenium Webdriver](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604)

One of the [suggested workarounds](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop) is to *simulate HTML5 drag and drop* via JavaScript:

- download [`drag_and_drop_helper.js`](https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544)
- execute the script via `execute_script()` calling `simulateDragDrop()` function on a `source` element passing the `target` element as a `dropTarget`

Sample code:

```
with open("drag_and_drop_helper.js") as f:
    js = f.read()

driver.execute_script(js + "$('#one').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#bin'});")
```

The problem is that it won't work in your case "as is" since it **requires `jQuery`**.

---

Now we need to figure out **how to dynamically load jQuery**. Thankfully, [there is a solution](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/3453/5574).

Complete working example in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

jquery_url = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://html5demos.com/drag")
driver.set_script_timeout(30)

# load jQuery helper
with open("jquery_load_helper.js") as f:
    load_jquery_js = f.read()

# load drag and drop helper
with open("drag_and_drop_helper.js") as f:
    drag_and_drop_js = f.read()

# load jQuery
driver.execute_async_script(load_jquery_js, jquery_url)

# perform drag&drop
driver.execute_script(drag_and_drop_js + "$('#one').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#bin'});")
```

where `jquery_load_helper.js` contains:

```
/** dynamically load jQuery */
(function(jqueryUrl, callback) {
    if (typeof jqueryUrl != 'string') {
        jqueryUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
    }
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var done = false;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = (function() {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded'
                    || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                done = true;
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                head.removeChild(script);
                callback();
            }
        });
        script.src = jqueryUrl;
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
})(arguments[0], arguments[arguments.length - 1]);
```

Before/after result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your example is still working. I have managed to translate it and use it in C#. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I converted this helper to native JS, removing the need for injecting jQuery: https://gist.github.com/druska/624501b7209a74040175

Comment: @DudumanBogdanVlad could you please share the C# version or any link?

Comment: @rahoolm I helped Raluca with this. She created a blog post. Here is the link http://ralucasuditu-softwaretesting.blogspot.ro/2015/08/selenium-webdriver-drag-and-drop-for.html

Comment: Thanks @DudumanBogdanVlad, I am looking into it. But in my case I want to drag and drop to XY. Say drag element one in x direction by 20 px. Please suggest.

Comment: Why don't you add another div at X/Y with a specific ID and drop your element in your new div? It's pretty the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for the late question, but I'm struggling here, when I copy the js snippet, it tells me that the last line (argument[0] etc) is out of a function, which is actually true so it does not work. I don't know much about JavaScript and can't understand what is the point of this last line, and how to fix it. Thanks for help !

Comment: Java version is in below commit

https://github.com/vikramvi/Selenium-Java/commit/a1354ca5854315fded8fc80ba24a4717927d08c7

Answer (score 2):

Found working example in python (without using jquery_load_helper.js) - https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544#gistcomment-2708388

Credits: [Kelanmomo](https://gist.github.com/kelanmomo)

As alecxe mentioned: download [drag_and_drop_helper.js](https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544)

```
# coding = utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop')

with open(os.path.abspath('drag_and_drop_helper.js'), 'r') as js_file:
    line = js_file.readline()
    script = ''
    while line:
        script += line 
        line = js_file.readline()

driver.execute_script(script + "$('#column-a').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#column-b'});")
sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly on this page, http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop.  But a similar solution does not work on this page, https://crossbrowsertesting.github.io/drag-and-drop.html, using something like   driver.execute_script(script +"$('#draggable').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#droppable'});").  I am trying to test pages like this, and cannot seem to get the drag/drop to happen.

Comment: Java version is in below commit

https://github.com/vikramvi/Selenium-Java/commit/a1354ca5854315fded8fc80ba24a4717927d08c7