# Protractor E2E test for angular html5 drag and drop

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, testing, protractor

As many of you know HTML5 drag and drop testing is not supported by protractor tests in AngularJS.

I got this drag-drop-helper.js on the net to simulate this drag and drop functionality. But when I tried to use it in my test spec by importing as node module

```
var dragdrop = require('./drag-drop-helper.js');
```

I'm getting the following error

> jquery not found

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You would need to dynamically load jquery and your drag and drop helper, see more at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381233/how-to-simulate-html5-drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver-in-python. Hope you can apply that solution to protractor.

Comment: Alecxe!  I have seen this solution, but not able to apply this to protractor

Answer (score 0):

Its not that well documented but the protractor API to look at lives under the browser object. Here's a link to the code which after a few reads becomes quite useful:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/actionsequence.js

You typically use it as follows:

```
browser
    .actions()
    .dragAndDrop(element(by.css(".queen")),{x:100,y:200})
    .perform();
```

See the dragAndDrop method in the link supplied for definitions :-)