# Run javascript file with selenium chrome driver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Followed the start guide, I can run a javascript snippet by using driver.execute(). How can I run external javascript files, which load some external modules itself.

Possible ways I can come up with:

1. Concatenate all required files into a single large file and then load it into a string and run it with driver.execute(). Possibly with help of a minifier.
2. Execute a small snippet to load all required js files.
3. Maybe modify the html before browser render it?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually load scripts dynamically via `execute_script()`. Here is an example use case where `jquery` library is dynamically loaded to support HTML5 drag&drop simulation:

- [How to simulate HTML5 Drag and Drop in Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29381233/771848)

The key functionality is the javascript code that is executed via `execute_async_script()` (taken from [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/3453/5574)) that adds a `script` element to `head` via `document.createElement()` on the fly.

The first link has a working example in Python, the second one has it in Java.

Comment: Is that possible execute_async_script returned after execute_script? Then execute_script will encounter an error?

Comment: @Shuo well, you need to make sure the required library is loaded before the usage..