# How to verify that a real drag and drop would work in selenium?

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29381532/2354849) and implemented its suggestions to simulate drag and drop within selenium. The issue is that the recommended [`drag_and_drop_helper.js`](https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544) didn't allow us to catch a bug in our application because it directly fires the `drop` event.

With HTML5 drag and drop it is important that you `preventDefault()` on the `dragover` event in order for the `drop` event to fire properly. The issue was that this `preventDefault()` was accidentally removed and broke the drag and drop of the application, but selenium was not able to catch this because the simulated drag and drop continued to work normally.

Is there a better way to simulate drag and drop that would have allowed catching this issue?