# How to drag and drop file with Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, drag-and-drop

I would like to check in my test (selenium / python) creating a new image on the site. I need to load a picture for it. How can I do this when I have the option to use the drop or file explorer field. As far as I know, I can not use the file explorer because there is no id or name. How to use the drag and drop method?

I have this code but it does not work:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_id ("file_upload")
element.send_keys ( "C: \\ Users \\ Desktop \\ Robert \\ Construct_ImminentCollision-C.jpg")
target = driver.find_element_by_id ("add-new-pano")

action_chains = ActionChains (driver)
action_chains.drag_and_drop (element, target) .perform ()
```

"add-new-pano" is the drop field id.

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't used selenium recently, if you're working in a static workspace where you can control most everything I would recommend using [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It isn't a dynamic solution, but it does contain [a left mouse emulation feature for drag and drop](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-drags).

In the provided example, the mouse moves from the 100,100 location towards the bottom of the screen by 100 pixels:

```
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100,100)    #starting mouse location of 100,100
>>> pyautogui.dragTo(100,200, button='left')     # drag mouse to X of 100, Y of 200 while holding down left mouse button
```

You can setup a makeshift solution to your application if it can be done in a controlled environment every time where you know the resolution, location of the file explorer, etc.

I have run into issues in a windows env. before due to unexpected update screens. Food for thought...

Answer (score 1):

The drag'n'drop of selenium is last time I checked broken.

I use the solution provided in [How to simulate HTML5 Drag and Drop in Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381233/how-to-simulate-html5-drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP intended. The OP mentioned that he wants to upload a picture to a website using the **drag and drop** method *programmatically*. Not by moving a puzzle-like element from a place to another.