# How to drag and drop a file from pc to webpage using selenium with python/javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, drag-and-drop

I have some files sored on my desktop and I want to drag and drop them to a webpage (there is a zone inside the webpage in which you can drag and drop your files)

I want to do that by using selenium with python or javascript
I know about the existence of ActionChains but I don't know if I can use it to simulate what i require...

Comment: Most sites with drag-and-drop also have a link on the page for "browse for files instead", which would likely be much easier to interact with in Selenium

Comment: Yeah but I'm working on a webpage and it does not have a browse only that place in which you have to drag and drop your file...

Comment: Some possible solutions discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281999/how-to-drag-and-drop-file-with-python-selenium), but the bottom line is no, you can't do it in Selenium alone. Selenium only automates the browser/webdriver, but there are other libraries to automate other GUI objects