# React drag&drop using python selenim/puppeteer

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, puppeteer

I need to test a drag and drop written in react 16.7.0. I tried using selenium and also puppeteer.

The puppeteer code is as bellow:

```
const temp_source = await iframe.$x("//div[@class='profile-item profile-item--draggable']//span[text()='pfsense_dut']")
const source = temp_source[0];

const temp_destination = await iframe.$x("//div[@class='component-network-diagram__diagram-layer']");

const destination = temp_destination[0];

const box_source = await source.boundingBox();
const box_destination = await destination.boundingBox();

await page.mouse.move(box_source.x + box_source.width / 2, box_source.y + box_source.height / 2);
await page.mouse.down();

await page.mouse.move(box_destination.x + box_destination.width / 2, box_destination.y + box_destination.height / 2, {steps:50});
await page.mouse.up();
```

I see the target element being clicked and dragged above the canvas (the drop zone), but nothing happens when dropping the element. Also no errors or exceptions are thrown.

The code for python with selenium is:

```
def dragAndDrop(self):
    try:
        ActionChains(self.driver).drag_and_drop(div_source,canvas_destination).perform()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        return False
```

Using python with selenium nothing happens: I don't even see the target element being selected. Using python with selenium, I receive an exception:

```
exception: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I even tried using the recommendations from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381233/how-to-simulate-html5-drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver) SO thread. The behavior is the same as the one seen with puppeteer.

What can be the possible issue with the drag and drop?

Comment: What your exception is trying to tell you is that one of the object that you are interacting with do not have a specific ID given to them. This could be the case of your XPATH being incorrect. I suggest you use the plugin Ranorex Selocity to find your XPATHS. 

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ranorex-selocity/ocgghcnnjekfpbmafindjmijdpopafoe?hl=en

Comment: I think the error is misleading.I checked the xpath of the element in dev console and the element is successfully found. Also, the puppeteer doesn't throw any errors. I will try to use your recommended plugin.