# Angular drag & drop with HTML5 not working through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, drag-and-drop, webdriverwait

My code does not working on demo AngularJS Drag and Drop list: http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import os

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple")
time.sleep(2)
source_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]')
dest_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.drag_and_drop(source_element, dest_element)
actions.perform()
time.sleep(10)
os.system("taskkill /im firefox.exe /f")
```

I try many solutions, but it is not working. By my opinion, problem is in "drop" action.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: not working, looks like weird

Comment: *not working* doesn't really mean anything. Do you get an exception? the elements don't move? something else?

Comment: element do not move into right list

Answer (score 0):

The elements on the webpage `http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple` are [html5](/questions/tagged/html5)[[image]angular](/questions/tagged/angular) elements. I took your code, made a couple of simple modifications and executed the **drag_and_drop** functionality through [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) and [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) and here are the observations:

### Firefox

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[text()='Demo: Simple Lists']")))
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
  source_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@dnd-list='list']/li[normalize-space()='Item A1']")))
  dest_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@dnd-list='list']/li[normalize-space()='Item B2']")))
  ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(source_element, dest_element).perform()
  ```
- Observation: Element with text as **Item A1** is **successfully** *dragged* but is never *dropped*. This issue can be reproduced using *Chrome* / *ChromeDriver* as well.
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: drag_n_drop]

---

### Conclusion

This is a known issue with **Selenium** and was discussed in details within the thread [HTML5 Drag and Drop with Selenium Webdriver](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604)

---

### Alternative

For a working solution you can follow the discussion in [How to simulate HTML5 Drag and Drop in Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381233/how-to-simulate-html5-drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver)

---

### Outro

You can find a detailed discussion in the **chromedriver** issue list [HTML5 drag and drop is not working](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2695) which is currently blocked by the **chromium** issue [Drag and drop not working through chrome debug protocol](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=850071)