# Why drag and drop is not working in IE 11 using Selenium Web driver (3.14.0)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iedriverserver

I am trying to perform drag and drop on IE browser (Version 11).

```
public void DragAndDrop(String source, String target) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    try {
        String basePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381233/how-to-simulate-html5-drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver
        // https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544
        final String JQUERY_LOAD_SCRIPT = (basePath + "/src/test/resources/jquery_load_helper.js");
        String jQueryLoader = readFile(JQUERY_LOAD_SCRIPT);

        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeAsyncScript(jQueryLoader /* , http://localhost:8080/jquery-1.7.2.js */);

        // ready to rock
        js.executeScript("jQuery(function($) { "
                + " $('input[name=\"q\"]').val('bada-bing').closest('form').submit(); " + " }); ");
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381233/how-to-simulate-html5-drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver
        // "where jquery_load_helper.js contains:"
        String filePath = basePath + "/src/test/resources/drag_and_drop_helper.js";

        // JQuery can ONLY work with id and css , xpath does NOT work with it.
        // String source = "//section[@id='wrapper']/article/ul/li[4]/a";

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            buffer.append(line);

        String javaScript = buffer.toString();

        javaScript = javaScript + "$('" + source + "').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '" + target + "'});";
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(javaScript);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**IEDriverServer.exe version is 3.14.0.0**

And below is the exception which I am getting while execution.

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: Error executing JavaScript
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'PRASHANTN', ip: '172.20.1.24', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:18913/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: a7a07929-b969-44cd-9db4-2e7d09406d28
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor28.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:485)
    at pageObjects.BasePage.DragAndDrop(BasePage.java:856)
    at pageObjects.MonitoringPage.dragNDrop(MonitoringPage.java:695)
    at testCases.MonitoringViewTest.selectCloseMenuOnCamToolbar(MonitoringViewTest.java:1330)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Why not actions class ?

Comment: its not working using it. So used above code for IE 11.

Comment: What is your binding language ? is it java ?

Comment: yes I am using java

Comment: Can you share URL also, I can have a look