# Selenium and onDragEnter

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

how to trigger `.onDragEnter` function, [like this one](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html)

```js
// init

// open page, wait load

const actions = await driver.actions();

const da1 = await driver.findElement(By.css('#todrag > span'));
const da2 = await driver.findElement(By.css('#mydropzone'));

await actions.dragAndDrop(da1, da2).perform();
```

`.dragAndDrop()` is not working, same as:

```js
await actions.move({origin: da1}).press().move({origin: da2}).release().perform();
```

---

*sounds like a bug yet*

specially because of my *left click* after `.perform()`, it stucks (sometime) & spawns `[Draggable 1]` item/obj to the my real one mouse icon

---

### #answer

cruisepandey > Are you sure that you are not missing `.build.perform()`?

```
.build.perform(); aaTypeError: Cannot read property 'perform' of undefined
.build().perform(); TypeError: actions.dragAndDrop(...).build is not a function
.build.perform(); aaTypeError: Cannot read property 'perform' of undefined
.build().perform(); TypeError: actions.move(...).press(...).move(...).release(...).build is not a function
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not missing `.build.perform()` ?

Answer (score 0):

it's not very clear what you want to do but I understand da2 click and move!!if you need to find and click go [https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#:~:text=find_element_by_class_name-,find_element_by_css_selector,-To%20find%20multiple](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#:%7E:text=find_element_by_class_name-,find_element_by_css_selector,-To%20find%20multiple)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Please download `drag_and_drop_helper.js` and then try this:

```
with open("drag_and_drop_helper.js") as f:
    js = f.read()

driver.execute_script(js + "$('#todrag > span').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#mydropzone'});")
```

More explanations can bee read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29381532/3485434)

Comment: thank you for reply, ref helps, but your answer is not finished yet; And there are #js tag 