# Selenium Webdriver (C#): Drag and Drop executed but nothing happens

Tags: selenium

I am unable to drag and drop the W3Schools image into the rectangle using the example code people have given before. I've tried Firefox, Chrome and IE webdrivers, nothing is happening.

Firefox version 26.0

Chrome version: 31.0.1650.63 m

Internet Explorer version: 11

```
     FirefoxDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(); //Open up a Firefox browser

     browser.Url = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp";
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // Wait so I can see what's happening
     IWebElement imageToDragAndDrop = browser.FindElementById("drag1");
     IWebElement boxToDragImageInto = browser.FindElementById("div2");

     Actions actions = new Actions(browser);

     // Attempt 1: Calling the DragAndDrop method did not work
     // actions.DragAndDrop(imageToDragAndDrop, boxToDragImageInto).Build().Perform(); 

     // Attempt 2: Calling the DragAndDrop method again but with the method calls on separate lines
     //actions.DragAndDrop(imageToDragAndDrop, boxToDragImageInto);
     //actions.Build();
     //actions.Perform();

     // Attempt 3: Calling the ClickAndHold, MoveToElement, Release methods did not work either
     actions.ClickAndHold(imageToDragAndDrop);
     actions.MoveToElement(boxToDragImageInto);
     actions.Release(imageToDragAndDrop);
     actions.Build();
     actions.Perform();
```

Comment: OK, downloaded the Selenium Webdriver source code and debugged the code. Turns out that actions.Build() clears the action.actionsList list leaving nothing for the Perform method to do. I removed the actions.Build() call and I am now going straight to actions.Perform() but still nothing is happening on the screen.

Comment: can u try the following: FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
IWebDriver browser= new FirefoxDriver(profile);
//Rest of the Code for Actions class and target and source elements actions.DragAndDrop(imageToDragAndDrop, boxToDragImageInto).Perform();

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested and it's still not dragging and dropping the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 drag and drop is a known issue for Selenium;

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6315&thanks=6315&ts=1380031813

Try using javascript directly as explained here;

[HTML5 Drag and Drop using Selenium Webdriver for Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797462/html5-drag-and-drop-using-selenium-webdriver-for-ruby)