# How to simulate HTML5 Drag and Drop in Selenium Webdriver in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, selenium-webdriver

I need the javascript (nodejs) version of the following code (Python) using [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver

with open("drag_and_drop_helper.js") as f:
js = f.read()

driver.execute_script(js + "$('#one').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#bin'});")
```

Here are the complete [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381233/how-to-simulate-html5-drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver-in-python) and [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797462/html5-drag-and-drop-using-selenium-webdriver-for-ruby?rq=1) implementations for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

With a working webdriver you can use:

driver.actions().dragAndDrop(driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('none')),driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('bin'))).perform();

Comment: @Raisus did you find a solution?